# How to receive a big encoded message in java client sended by c server?

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp, client-server

The problem here is that java client keeps waiting in an infinite while loop, and can't get the whole encoded message.

- while((String line = br.readLine()) != null)

The message is an encoded matrix of 300*300, and is like this

[Terminal Output of encoded Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvPyU.png)

The client java code look like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {

    private String encodedMsg="";

        public Tester(){
            try {
                Socket s1 = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
                InputStream s1in = s1.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(s1in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String word="",line="";

                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                  word+=line;
                }
               //String line = br.readLine();
               System.out.println("Word is: "+word);

                System.out.println("Message received from client is "+this.encodedMsg);

            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Tester();
    }
}
```

I think that the connection beetwen C server and Java client its well established because when i replace the while loop with br.readline for just one reading, the output is 'W', the first character of the encoded message.

Extra: This is a given task and i need to send a processed bmp file, from server c to client java, for visualizing on the client with some UI. The thing is that i need to refresh this bmp file to make it look like a gif.
I was trying to send the image directly by reading chunks of bytes but i gived up on reading chunks in client side.

If you need to know more about the code just let me know.
Thanks for your time!!

EDIT: 
Here is the code in server side

```
#include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <stdint.h>
            #include <unistd.h>
            #include <errno.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <time.h>
            #include <fcntl.h>
            #include <sys/types.h>
            #include <sys/stat.h>
            #include <sys/socket.h>
            #include <netinet/in.h>
            #include <arpa/inet.h>

            #include <math.h>

            #define MIN 0
            #define MAX 1
            #define K 0.00125

            #define F_MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
            #define F_MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

            struct sockaddr_in c_addr;
            char fname[100];
             /*
              * ==================================
              * BARRA DE PROGRESO
              * ==================================
              */
            void barra(int porc, int total, int larg){
                int i;
                fflush(stdout);

              printf("\r[");
              for(i=0;i<larg;i++){
                if( (100*i)/larg>(100*porc)/total )
                   putchar('_');
                else
                   putchar('#');
              }
              printf("] %d%% Completado...",(uint32_t)((float)(100*porc)/(float)(total)) );
             }
             /*FIN barra()*/

            /*
             *  ==================================
             *    FUNCIONES RELACIONADAS CON EL PASO
             *    DE ARGUMENTOS AL PROGRAMA
             *  ==================================
             */

            /*
             *  Argumentos de entrada y configuracion de getopt
             */
             struct args_net{
                char name[100];
                FILE * file_ptr;
                int connfd;
                int listenfd;
                char encodedMsg[999999];

             } net_args;


            struct args_t{
                uint32_t tamano_grilla;
                uint32_t num_pasos;
                uint8_t  barra;
                char*    dir_bmp;
                uint32_t  delta_time;
            } args;

            static const char *optString = "N:T:m:d:hb";

            /*
             *  Funcion que imprime en stdout el uso
             *  del programa.
             */
            void print_usage(char* name){
                printf("Uso: %s -N tamano_grilla -T num_pasos\n", name);
                printf("\t    [-b] [-m out_dir -d delta_time] [-h]\n");
                printf("\nParametros:\n");
                printf("\t-N : Tamaño de la grilla de simulación.\n");
                printf("\t-T : Nro de pasos de la simulación.\n");
                printf("\t-b : Si esta presente, se muestra una barra de progreso.\n" );
                printf("\t-m : Si esta presente, almacena imagenes BMP de la simulacion en out_dir.\n" );
                printf("\t     Cada imagen se crea en el intervalo de tiempo especificado en -d. Por\n" );
                printf("\t     omisión, delta_time=20\n" );
                printf("\t-h : Si esta presente, muestra este mensaje y termina.\n" );
            }
            /* FIN print_usage()*/

            /*
             *  Funcion que comprueba el ingreso de parametros
             *  al programa segun seccion 5 del documento LAB1
             */
            void check_args(int argc , char **argv){
                int opcion;

                args.tamano_grilla    = 0;
                args.num_pasos        = 0;
                args.barra            = 0;
                args.dir_bmp          = NULL;
                args.delta_time       = 20;

                while ((opcion = getopt (argc, argv, optString)) != -1){
                    switch (opcion) {
                        case 'N':
                            args.tamano_grilla = atoi(optarg);
                            break;
                        case 'T':
                            args.num_pasos = atoi(optarg);
                            break;
                        case 'm':
                            args.dir_bmp = malloc(strlen(optarg)*sizeof(char));
                            strcpy(args.dir_bmp, optarg);
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            args.delta_time = atoi(optarg);
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            args.barra = 1;
                            break;
                        case 'h':
                        default:
                            print_usage(argv[0]);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }

                if ( args.tamano_grilla==0  ||
                     args.num_pasos == 0  ) {
                    print_usage(argv[0]);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }


            }
            /* FIN check_args()*/


            /*
             *  ==================================
             *    FUNCIONES RELACIONADAS CON
             *    USO DE MATRICES
             *  ==================================
             */

            void matrix_inicializar(float **matrix) {
                uint32_t i,j;

                for (i = 0; i < args.tamano_grilla; i++) {
                    if((matrix[i] = (float *)malloc(args.tamano_grilla*sizeof(float))) == NULL){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error en malloc en datos_onda[%u]\n",i);
                        perror("");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    for ( j = 0; j < args.tamano_grilla; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            /*FIN matrix_inicializar()*/

            void matrix_condicion_inicial(float **matrix){
                uint32_t i, j;
                uint32_t ii[2], jj[2];

                ii[MIN] = (uint32_t)(0.4*args.tamano_grilla);
                ii[MAX] = (uint32_t)(0.6*args.tamano_grilla);

                jj[MIN] = (uint32_t)(0.4*args.tamano_grilla);
                jj[MAX] = (uint32_t)(0.6*args.tamano_grilla);

                for(i = ii[MIN]; i < ii[MAX]; i++) {
                    for(j = jj[MIN]; j < jj[MAX]; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = 20;
                    }
                }
            }
            /*FIN matrix_condicion_inicial()*/

            void matrix_print(float **matrix) {
                uint32_t i,j;
                for (i = 0; i < args.tamano_grilla; i++) {
                    for ( j = 0; j < args.tamano_grilla; j++) {
                        printf("%f\t", matrix[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            /*FIN matrix_print()*/

            FILE * matrix_to_bmp(float **matrix, char * filename, uint8_t color) {
                uint32_t max_RGB  = 0xFFFFFF;

                uint32_t headers[13];
                FILE * outfile;
                int extrabytes, paddedsize;
                int x, y, n;

                extrabytes = 4 - ((args.tamano_grilla * 3) % 4);  // How many bytes of padding to add to each
                                                                // horizontal line - the size of which must
                                                                // be a multiple of 4 bytes.
                if (extrabytes == 4)
                extrabytes = 0;

                paddedsize = ((args.tamano_grilla * 3) + extrabytes) * args.tamano_grilla;

                // Headers...
                // Note that the "BM" identifier in bytes 0 and 1 is NOT included in these "headers".

                headers[0]  = paddedsize + 54;      // bfSize (whole file size)
                headers[1]  = 0;                    // bfReserved (both)
                headers[2]  = 54;                   // bfOffbits
                headers[3]  = 40;                   // biSize
                headers[4]  = args.tamano_grilla;  // biWidth
                headers[5]  = args.tamano_grilla; // biHeight

                // Would have biPlanes and biBitCount in position 6, but they're shorts.
                // It's easier to write them out separately (see below) than pretend
                // they're a single int, especially with endian issues...

                headers[7]  = 0;                    // biCompression
                headers[8]  = paddedsize;           // biSizeImage
                headers[9]  = 0;                    // biXPelsPerMeter
                headers[10] = 0;                    // biYPelsPerMeter
                headers[11] = 0;                    // biClrUsed
                headers[12] = 0;                    // biClrImportant

                outfile = fopen(filename, "wb");

                //
                // Headers begin...
                // When printing ints and shorts, we write out 1 character at a time to avoid endian issues.
                //

                fprintf(outfile, "BM");

                for (n = 0; n <= 5; n++) {
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", headers[n] & 0x000000FF);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & (unsigned int) 0xFF000000) >> 24);
                }

                // These next 4 characters are for the biPlanes and biBitCount fields.

                fprintf(outfile, "%c", 1);
                fprintf(outfile, "%c", 0);
                fprintf(outfile, "%c", 24);
                fprintf(outfile, "%c", 0);

                for (n = 7; n <= 12; n++) {
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", headers[n] & 0x000000FF);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                   fprintf(outfile, "%c", (headers[n] & (unsigned int) 0xFF000000) >> 24);
                }

                //
                // Headers done, now write the data...
                //

                for (y = args.tamano_grilla - 1; y >= 0; y--) {    // BMP image format is written from bottom to top...
                    for (x = 0; x <= (int)args.tamano_grilla - 1; x++) {

                        float a = (matrix[x][y]) / 10.0;

                        uint32_t a_scaled = a*max_RGB;

                        uint32_t R = 0xFF - ((a_scaled & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
                        uint32_t G = 0xFF - ((a_scaled & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
                        uint32_t B = 0xFF - ((a_scaled & 0x000000ff));

                        uint32_t Gray = (R+G+B)/3;
                        if (color == 0) {
                            R = Gray;
                            G = Gray;
                            B = Gray;
                        }

                        fprintf(outfile, "%c", R);
                        fprintf(outfile, "%c", G);
                        fprintf(outfile, "%c", B);

                    }
                  if (extrabytes){      // See above - BMP lines must be of lengths divisible by 4.
                    for (n = 1; n <= extrabytes; n++) {
                        fprintf(outfile, "%c", 0);
                    }
                  }
                }

                fclose(outfile);

                /* Archivo Finalizado... se puede enviar ahora */


                return outfile;
            }
            /*FIN matrix_to_bmp()*/

            void* SendFileToClient(struct args_net * frame)
            {
                  //int connfd=frame->connfd;

                  printf("Connection accepted and id: %d\n",frame->connfd);
                  printf("Connected to Clent: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(c_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(c_addr.sin_port));
                  write(frame->connfd, frame->name,256);

                    FILE *fp = fopen(frame->name,"rb");
                    if(fp==NULL)
                    {
                        printf("File opern error");
                        return 0;   
                    }   

                    /* Read data from file and send it */
                    while(!feof(fp))
                    {
                        /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
                        unsigned char buff[1024]={0};
                        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp); //lee lo que esta dentro del archivo...
                        printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        

                        /* If read was success, send data. */
                        if(nread > 0)
                        {
                            printf("Sending \n");
                            write(frame->connfd, buff, nread);
                        }
                        if (nread < 1024)
                        {
                            if (feof(fp)){
                                printf("End of file\n");
                                printf("File transfer completed for id: %d\n",frame->connfd);
                        }
                            if (ferror(fp))
                                printf("Error reading\n");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            printf("Closing Connection for id: %d\n",frame->connfd);
            shutdown(frame->connfd,SHUT_WR);
            sleep(2);
            }

            void* Networking(struct args_net *frame){


                size_t clen=0;
                int err;
                pthread_t tid; 
                    clen=sizeof(c_addr);
                    printf("Waiting...\n");
                    frame->connfd = accept(frame->listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&c_addr,&clen); //connfd => clientSocket, en este espera hasta que el cliente solicite conexión.
                    if(frame->connfd<0){
                        printf("Error in accept\n"); 
                    }
                    if(write(frame->connfd,frame->encodedMsg,strlen(frame->encodedMsg)!=-1)){
                        write(frame->connfd, '\n', 1);
                        printf("%s message send",frame->encodedMsg);
                    }

            }

            const char * Encode(float **matrix){
                int n=0;
                uint32_t i,j;
                char word[999999];
                int e = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < args.tamano_grilla; i++) {
                    for ( j = 0; j < args.tamano_grilla; j++) {
                        n= (int)matrix[i][j];
                        /*  1.- Sign Token   */ 

                        if(n >= 0){
                            word[e]='W';

                        } else {
                            word[e]='w';
                        }
                        e++;
                        word[e]='.';
                        e++;


                        switch(n){
                            case 0:
                            word[e]= 'A';
                                break;
                            case 1:
                            word[e]= 'B';
                                break;
                            case 2:
                            word[e]= 'C';
                                break;
                            case 3:
                            word[e]= 'D';
                                break;
                            case 4:
                            word[e]= 'E';
                                break;
                            case 5:
                            word[e]= 'F';
                                break;
                            case 6:
                            word[e]= 'G';
                                break;
                            case 7:
                            word[e]= 'H';
                                break;
                            case 8:
                            word[e]= 'I';
                                break;
                            case 9:
                            word[e]= 'J';
                                break;
                            case 10:
                            word[e]= 'K';
                                break;
                            case 11:
                            word[e]= 'L';
                                break;
                            case 12:
                            word[e]= 'M';
                                break;
                            case 13:
                            word[e]= 'N';
                                break;
                            case 14:
                            word[e]= 'O';
                                break;
                            case 15:
                            word[e]= 'P';
                                break;
                            case 16:
                            word[e]= 'Q';
                                break;
                            case 17:
                            word[e]= 'R';
                                break;
                            case 18:
                            word[e]= 'S';
                                break;
                            case 19:
                            word[e]= 'T';
                                break;
                            case 20:
                            word[e]= 'U';
                                break;
                            default:
                                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                break;
                        }

                            e++;
                            word[e] ='-'; //Number token
                            e++;

                    }//End of Row


                        word[e] ='/'; //Row token
                        e++;

                } //End for
                word[e] = '\n';
                return &word;
            }


            int main(int argc , char **argv) {

                /*
                 *  H[k][i][j]
                 *      k: k-ésima matriz k={0,1,2}
                 *      i: i-ésima fila de la matriz k
                 *      j: j-ésima columna de la matriz k
                 */

                struct args_net frame;

                struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
                int listenfd = 0,ret;
                char sendBuff[1025];
                int numrv;



                float** H[3];
                FILE * file_ptr;
                pthread_t thnet;
                char fname[256];
                uint32_t i,j, t;
                uint8_t en_color = 0;

                frame.listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Creando el Socket TCP
                if(frame.listenfd<0)
                {
                  printf("Error in socket creation\n");
                  exit(2);
                }

                printf("Socket retrieve success\n");

                serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
                serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

                ret=bind(frame.listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)); //Asignando un puerto al socket
                if(ret<0)
                {
                  printf("Error in bind\n");
                  exit(2);
                }

                if(listen(frame.listenfd, 10) == -1) //listen(serverSocket, MAXenEspera(creo)) -> Set socket to listen.
                {
                    printf("Failed to listen\n");
                    return -1;
                }

                check_args(argc,argv);

                H[0] = (float **)malloc(args.tamano_grilla*sizeof(float*));
                H[1] = (float **)malloc(args.tamano_grilla*sizeof(float*));
                H[2] = (float **)malloc(args.tamano_grilla*sizeof(float*));

                if(H[0] == NULL ||
                   H[1] == NULL||
                     H[2] == NULL){
                    perror("Error en malloc() para H[][]");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                /*
                 *  Create directory to save image
                 *  
                 */
                if (args.dir_bmp != NULL) {
                    int8_t res;
                    char cmd[128];

                    sprintf(cmd, "rm -rf %s", args.dir_bmp);
                    res = system(cmd);
                    if(res == -1){
                        fprintf(stderr, "No se puede eliminar el directorio de salida %s\n", args.dir_bmp);
                        perror("");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    res = mkdirat(AT_FDCWD, args.dir_bmp, S_IRWXU);
                    if(res == -1){
                        fprintf(stderr, "No se puede crear el directorio de salida %s\n", args.dir_bmp);
                        perror("");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }

                puts("==============================================");
                printf("Tamaño grilla         : %u\n", args.tamano_grilla);
                printf("Nro de pasos          : %u\n", args.num_pasos);
                if (args.dir_bmp != NULL) {
                  printf("Directorio salida BMP : %s\n", args.dir_bmp);
                    printf("Intervalo imágenes    : %u\n", args.delta_time);
                }
                puts("==============================================");


                matrix_inicializar(H[0]);
                matrix_inicializar(H[1]);
                matrix_inicializar(H[2]);




                    for ( t = 0; t <= args.num_pasos; t++) {
                        if (args.barra == 1) {
                            barra(t, args.num_pasos, 50);
                        }

                        if (t > 1) {
                            for ( i = 1; i < (args.tamano_grilla-1); i++) {
                                for ( j = 1; j < (args.tamano_grilla-1); j++) {
                                    H[t%3][i][j] = 2*H[(t-1)%3][i][j] - H[(t-2)%3][i][j] +
                                                K * (
                                                    H[(t-1)%3][i+1][j] +
                                                    H[(t-1)%3][i-1][j] +
                                                    H[(t-1)%3][i][j-1] +
                                                    H[(t-1)%3][i][j+1] -
                                                    4*H[(t-1)%3][i][j]
                                                );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (t == 1) { /* Interacion 1*/
                            for ( i = 1; i < (args.tamano_grilla-1); i++) {
                                for ( j = 1; j < (args.tamano_grilla-1); j++) {
                                    H[1][i][j] = H[0][i][j] +
                                                K * (
                                                    H[0][i+1][j] +
                                                    H[0][i-1][j] +
                                                    H[0][i][j-1] +
                                                    H[0][i][j+1] -
                                                    4*H[0][i][j]
                                                );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (t == 0) {/*Initial Condition*/
                            matrix_condicion_inicial(H[0]);
                        }

                        if (args.dir_bmp == NULL) {
                            if ( (t % args.delta_time) == 0) {

                                sprintf(fname, "C%06d.bmp", t);
                                strcpy(frame.name,fname);

                                printf("%s\n", frame.name);
                                printf("%s\n", fname);

                                //Encoding Matrix
                                strcpy(frame.encodedMsg,Encode(H[t%3]));

                                //Network Stuff
                                Networking(&frame);
                        }
                    /*END for()*/
                    }
                        while(1){}

                printf("\nEnd simulation\n");

                return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
```

Comment: It depends on what exactly is sent by the C server.  The server and the Java client need to agree on exactly what the format of the data sent over the network is.  You need to show what the C server is sending.

Comment: You can't use readline on binary data.

Comment: And how it must be?

Comment: You can't use a `Reader` on binary data. You must use an `InputStream`.